# upload base64 (file) to php server via node js

Tags: php, node.js, base64

I currently have a situation where FormData doesn't work for me.  I'm using a specific "engine" Adobe CEP which is a little antiquated and the formData causes issues.  My solution was to upload a file directly via base64 encoding.  From Node JS I do:

```
let buff = new Buffer(filePath);
let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
console.log(base64data);
```

The console.log gives me the string:

```
Li4vLi4vLi4vLi4vLi4vLi4vLi4vVXNlcnMvb21hcmd1em1hbi8vRGVza3RvcC9Zb28vYWkyaHRtbC1vdXRwdXQvaG9tZS1wcm8tQXJ0Ym9hcmRfMS5qcGc=

  axios.post(API_ENDPOINT, base64data)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

From here I upload to a php server via axios.
The server receives it and I do:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
file_put_contents('testmeimg.jpg', base64_decode($data));
echo 'completed';
?>
```

another attempt

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('testmeimg.jpg', base64_decode($data));
var_dump($data);

"string(120) "Li4vLi4vLi4vLi4vLi4vLi4vLi4vVXNlcnMvb21hcmd1em1hbi8vRGVza3RvcC9Zb28vYWkyaHRtbC1vdXRwdXQvaG9tZS1wcm8tQXJ0Ym9hcmRfMS5qcGc="
"
```

The file correctly gets saved to my server but it's damaged and unreadable.
It also appears with zero bytes.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong? or how I should handle this b64?

Comment: Did you "upload" as JSON? If yes, you put a JSON string into the file. It will be corrupt, because you do not decode a complete base64 string.

Comment: Yes and I decode it here: $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') ); is this what you were referring to? @MarkusZeller

Comment: This can not work! Again: You are putting invalid image data into a image file. The base64_decode() will fail.

Comment: @MarkusZeller ok yes it's NOT working but what is the solution?

Comment: Echo $data and you will see.

Comment: Ok I see it but how would I do it? I can't use formData @MarkusZeller

Comment: Since you didn't show how exactly are you sending the base64 encoded file, we can't tell you what are you doing wrong. I doubt that you just JSON encoded the string itself, so your PHP code should be throwing an error.

Comment: And if you don't intend to send any other data than the file itself, I don't see any need to use JSON or even base64. You are basically overcomplicating [the PUT method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

Comment: Ok I updated to show how I am sending the JSON file and also I don't convert to JSON when Axios sends it makes it a json string.  @gre_gor

Comment: With that Axios call added, I don't see any JSON going on at all. It looks like you're posting the raw base64-string. If you `var_dump($data)` on the PHP side, does it contain any value at all or is it `NULL`? If it's `NULL`, try removing the `json_decode()` step. The output you're expecting for `var_dump($data)` is `string(N) "Li4vLi4v...."` where N is the number of characters in your base64-string.

Comment: Sidenote and different issue: when I decode your base64 string, the value is a string containing the relative path to the image file, not the raw binary image data.

Comment: @rickdenhaan THANK YOU for the great help up to this point.  I'll check on that base64 string and also I added the response from the server with a var_dump.  Maybe it's not a side note if the file name isn't streaming right that might be part of the issue no?  I'll check that also

Comment: Okay, so `$data` contains the correct value and that string [does decode from base64](https://3v4l.org/RAW4S). Next step is to check if that image file is writable. If you temporarily remove all that code and just do something like `file_put_contents('testmeimg.jpg', "hello");` -- is the file 5 bytes large containing the text "hello" if you open it in a text editor?

Comment: @rickdenhaan actually now the jpg is created with the decoded string the file path.

Comment: Progress! Now you just need to send the actual file data instead of the file name :-) You can probably use `fs.readFileSync(filePath)` for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat] please? (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247532/discussion-between-fabriciog-and-rickdenhaan). @rickdenhaan

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great help by @rickdenhaan aka the man.
I changed my node buffer code to:

```
   let buff = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
    let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
```

Previously I wasn't sending the file buffer only the path as a buffer.

Then on the php side this worked:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('testmeimg.jpg', base64_decode($data));
```